# Sorting images into a list by date from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to call another function to solve this function, but I get this error saying that this file is not defined, even though it was defined in another function.

```
 filename_dict = create_image_dict(open_csv_file)
 builtins.NameError: name 'open_csv_file' is not defined
```

I'm wondering if there was a different and better way to do this. Can anyone please help me out?

```
def sorted_images(image_dict):
'''(dict) -> list of str

Given an image dictionary return a list of the filenames
sorted by date. 

>>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], \
'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-04', 'Happy Sat.']}
>>> sorted_images(d)    
['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
'''
new_list = []
filename_dict = create_image_dict(open_csv_file)
sub_dict = filename_dict[filename]
early_date = 0
early_filename = ''
for (location, date, caption) in sub_dict.items():
    if date > early_date:
        early_filename = filename
        new_list.append(early_filename)
return new_list
```

Comment: where do you define "open_csv_file"? can you post the whole code?

Comment: I defined it in another function. I'm trying to call the other function.

Comment: so..... wheer is the other function? I need to see the scopes, maybe it's out of scope, I mean, if I declare a variable in my pc, you will cannot see it

Comment: But if I call another function, isn't it supposed to check the other function?

Comment: You get that error. Maybe the scope is different, or `open_csv_file` is not global either.

Comment: What do you mean by global?

Answer (score 0):

```
# With lambda expression

def sorted_images(image_dict):
    result = sorted(image_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x[1].split('-'))
    return [image for (image, exif) in image_dict.items() for (_exif) in result if (exif == _exif)]

# Without lambda expression


def sort_by_date(x):
    return x[1].split('-')

def sorted_images(image_dict):
    result = sorted(image_dict.values(), key=sort_by_date )
    return [image for (image, exif) in image_dict.items() for (_exif) in result if (exif == _exif)]
```

This is a function that does just that with the data you specified.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what lamda is. Could you do it without lambda?

Comment: @bigd: `lambda`s are just anonymous functions that consist of a single expression (that they return implicitly). You could do `def splitdate(x): return x[1].split('-')` then use it as `sorted(image_dict.values(), key=splitdate)` and the effect would be the same; `lambda` is just a shorthand when the function isn't really useful otherwise (so short you wouldn't even use a function if you didn't need a callback function, as in this case), so making a named function to use it just the once is pointless.

Comment: @bigd I've updated the solution. I removed the lambda expression. I hope this helps.

Comment: I mean can we do it without creating another function, like just using the function that was given?

Comment: @bigd the function you gave lacked some parameters, that's why I rewrote the function. --- Knowing the context of the initial function would really help.

Comment: The original function is creating a list of str from a dictionary.

Comment: @bigd The function I wrote does exactly that. Or is there any other requirement ?

Comment: It does, but is there a way to do it without writing another function and lambda?